# Is it possible to write a raw pointer wrapper with support for "array_conversion" when adding const?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Consider the following minimal class ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/EqEWjKEqf)) as a motivating example for my question:

```
class A {
public:
   explicit A(std::vector<int *> elements): _elements(elements) {}
   auto get_elements() const -> std::span<int const * const> { return _elements; };
private:
   std::vector<int *> _elements;
};
```

Internally, we store a vector of pointers (that can be freely changed by other member functions). We expose a `std::span` that should not even be allow to modify through the pointers.

I would like to use a custom pointer wrapper class instead of raw pointers (the concrete additional feature is not important here). Is it somehow possible to implement this "array_conversion" for a pointer wrapper?

For example, `std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::observer_ptr`, which is intended as a near drop-in replacement for pointers (with additional features), does not work ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/sPf17eeaY)):

```
using std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::observer_ptr;

static_assert(std::is_convertible<int *(*)[], int const * const(*)[]>::value);
//This is different for the raw pointer and the wrapper
static_assert(not std::is_convertible<observer_ptr<int>(*)[], observer_ptr<int const> const(*)[]>::value);

auto main() -> int {
   auto vec = std::vector<observer_ptr<int>>{1};
   auto span = std::span<observer_ptr<int>>{vec};
   auto const_span = std::span<observer_ptr<int const> const>{span};
   return 0;
}
```

I do not want to construct the span in a different way (for example by introducing const_casts), because this would have to be done at every place and becomes quite ugly. Furthermore, the limitation really is the pointer wrapper here.

So my question is whether can be any pointer wrapper that supports this feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without ugly conversions.

`S<T>*` (pointer to S containing `T*`) can't be implicitly converted to `S<const T>*` (pointer to S containing `const T*`). For example, this conversion doesn't work:

```
auto x = std::make_shared<int>(1);
std::shared_ptr<const int>* x2{&x};
```

Likewise `span<S<T>>` can't be implicitly converted to `span<S<const T>>`. For example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v = {x};
std::span<std::shared_ptr<int>> s{v};
std::span<std::shared_ptr<const int>> s2{s}; // doesn't work
std::span<std::shared_ptr<const int>> s3{s.data(), s.size()}; // doesn't work
```

Nevertheless, an ugly cast is possible:

```
std::span<std::shared_ptr<const int>> s4{reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<const int>*>(s.data()), s.size()};
std::span<const std::shared_ptr<const int>> s5{reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<const int>*>(s.data()), s.size()};
```

If you are sure with your particular smart pointer type that this reinterpret_cast doesn't lead to any side effects, you could have it in your `get_elements()` method, to not have to duplicate it at every place:

```cpp
std::span<const S<const int>> get_elements() const {
    return std::span<const S<const int>>{reinterpret_cast<S<const int>*>(_elements.data()), _elements.size()};
}
```